# Corona SDK While loop crash

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What is wrong with this code that it crashes the simulator?
I'm new to Corona SDK, but I know alot of Lua from Roblox.

```
local x,y,touching,active = 2,2,false,true
local background = display.newImage("Icon.png",(display.pixelWidth/2)+30,y)
background:scale(60,60)
print("Started")

function move()
    y=y+1
end

function onObjectTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        touching = true
        while touching == true do
            timer.performWithDelay( 1000, move)
        end
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        touching = false
    end
    return true
end

background:addEventListener("touch",onObjectTouch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Corona is event based.  You essentially lock up the touch event in a while loop which prevents the ended phase from triggering to break your endless loop.

Corona has a Runtime event called "enterframe".  It is called 30-60 times a second (probably less depending on the work it is doing) that is essentially an update method.

Using your logic:

```
function onObjectTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        touching = true           
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        touching = false
    end
end

funtion EnterFrame(event)
    if touching == true then
            timer.performWithDelay( 1000, move)
    end
end
```

There are other ways to accomplish this by setting a dynamic objects velocity when the touch is started and setting that velocity to 0 when the touch ends.